# Which game do these dice belong to?

Tags: identify-this-game, dice

[image]

I found these dice, but I dont know which game they belong to... any help is appreciated.

The red dice has only D's (in yellow) and 0's on it; The green dice has -2, -1, 0, 1, 2 on it and only one 3 with a circle around it (as shown); The black dice has two symbols on either end and the following numbers: 10, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60

Comment: Could you describe the faces we Cabot see in the picture, please?

Comment: The red dice has only D's (in yellow) and 0's on it;  The green dice has -2, -1, 0, 1, 2 on it and only one 3 with a circle around it (as shown); The black dice has two symbols on either end and the following numbers: 10, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60

Answer (score 16):

This is [Go Long](https://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/39552/golong-football-dice-game), a game about (American) football.

The black die is for yards gained, if I remember correctly.

Here's an image of the dice from Go Long (from BoardGameGeek):

[image: The dice from Go Long]

Comment: And the symbol on the black die is a field goal, I take it?

Comment: Or a touchdown...? Can't be bothered to check the rules. The game was pretty forgettable.